# Django decorator to redirect based on user-type

Tags: python, django, decorator, django-authentication

Currently in my django app, I have two kind of users, say userTypeA and userTypeB.

At this point, I redirect both of the types to  /usercheck/ which has a function to check the type of user, and redirect them accordingly. This is working out pretty well.

However, just for curiosity, if I were to write a decorator where would I put it ?

One place I can think of is settings.py where a decorator will output different LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL based on the user type.

It is just for learning. My current implementation is working out pretty good so far.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`settings.py` is meant for global static configuration data, I would definitely not try dynamically changing the settings. There are many other places in Django where a login url can be set explicitly.

I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do, but it sounds like the `user_passes_test` decorator is what you're after. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test):

> **Limiting access to logged-in users that pass a test:** The simple way is to run your test on `request.user` in the view directly.... As a shortcut, you can use the convenient `user_passes_test` decorator.

Comment: Wow, I did not know such thing existed. I ended up doing something similar: assigning a default redirect, and then overriding this default based on conditions. I could have used this one. Anyway, thanks a lot.